# Managing secrets with Chef

Tags: chef-infra

It is unclear to me how secrets can be best managed with Chef in a reliable and predictable way.

What I have tried is to put all secrets logic in a separate cookbook which then depends on all cookbooks that it is managing secrets for.

That way - I thought - secrets could be handled in a consistent way in a single place. Another benefit is that I don't have to change existing cookbooks.

This secrets cookbook is fetching secrets from encrypted data bags and using that to set passwords/secret attributes. To prevent secrets being uploaded to Chef server I blacklist all attributes that I don't want uploaded.

For some cookbooks this has the desired effect but for others results become really unpredictable. To the point I am now convinced this is not the way to go about it. What is the recommended way to do this? I don't want to change existing cookbooks.

So for example if there is cookbook with something like

```
execute 'change first install root password' do
  # Add sensitive true when foodcritic #233 fixed
  command '/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password \'' + \
    node['mariadb']['server_root_password'] + '\''
  action :nothing
  not_if { node['mariadb']['server_root_password_2'].empty? }
end
```

What is the best way to turn attribute `['mariadb']['server_root_password']` in a secret and retrieve it's value from encrypted data bag? I don't want to change the cookbook and I don't want the password uploaded to the server.

**Update**

I think the issues are result of bug in `blacklist_node_attrs` causing blacklisted attributes to be unavailable during Chef run.

But the whole attributes approach in combination with secrets is largely undeveloped in Chef it seems. Which is amazing.

Current status is that if you want to manage secrets you will have to change existing cookbooks. If you try cookbook attributes in attribute files and recipe files you will discover that outcomes are random. In some situations it will work, in others it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting secrets in node attributes is, shall we say, very unwise. As you noted, they get saved back up to the Chef Server in the clear. That cookbook will have to be updated if you don't want to end up with a very fragile solution. There is no generic solution, though I'm working on one probably to be released in another month or two. I've got a lot of words about this on coderanger.net that I'm guessing you've run in to (since the title of this question is also the title of one of my blog posts). Ping me on Slack or IRC (I'm in UTC+11 for another few days, and then will be back in UTC-7) and I can try to give you something more tailored to your use case. Overall the short version is that this is all terrible and there are no good answers currently.

Comment: This is the post I think https://coderanger.net/chef-secrets/. That is a clear thorough answer to my question.

Comment: Also check out the talk linked there, it's more up to date by a few years and much more in depth about the options. I've got another more recent post about using hashicorp vault with chef, but for now it's just a proposal. Stay tuned?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating/experimenting with encrypted data bags the conclusion inevitably reached is that Chef currently does not really have a solution for managing secrets.

There are of course encrypted data bags, vaults etc but these practices conflict with the practice of not changing community/existing/third party cookbooks just for the sake of managing secrets in a secure way.

The point is that encrypted data bags etc require us to make changes to cookbooks. Not a problem if the cookbooks are your own but if you use community cookbooks it is not recommended to change these.